# Объектно-ориентированная модель

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyqt5

Пишу программу(эмулятор телефона) и не могу вообразить, как она должна быть в ООП. Прошу помощи у бывалых.

[image: телефон и кнопки]
**Состояние: Заблокированный(Включенный)** и я подсветил кнопки, чтобы дальше было понятно

Как это должно работать:

1. Я использую PyQt и планирую запускать программу так:

   `app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    phone = Phone()
    phone.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())`
2. Я планирую создать класс Phone() и в нем создать еще несколько "элементов"(элементы в кавычках, так как я затрудняють ответить, как это будет реализовано).
   Телефон ведь изначально может быть в двух состояниях: **Выключенный** и **Включенный**(а тут уже в свою очередь **Заблокированный** или **Активный**(а тут Главный экран или Настройки, или Звонки и т.д.))
3. Основная моя проблема в том, что я не знаю как телефон будет менять состояния(их я и назвал "элементами"). Это должны быть функции(что, думаю, я смогу реализовать) или же классы(что я хочу, но не знаю, надо ли и будет ли это правильно). Идея такова: сначала телефон **Выключенный**(естественно, при этом кнопки Громкости и Блокировки(они у меня тоже будут) не работают). Дальше мы удерживаем(или нажимаем, тут уже как получится) кнопку Громкости и телефон включается и кнопки Громкости и Блокировки становятся активными!. Так вот эта активация(setVisible(True) или что-то типо того) кнопок *должна происходить через функцию или должен поменяться класс?*
4. Знаю, последний вариант звучит бредово, но очень уж хочется сделать клас Телефон(например, загрузка картинки, создание всех кнопок), потом **Выключенный(тоже самое, что в Телефон)** и **Включенный(меняется картинка на начальную и кнопки становятся активными)**. А там и **Заблокированный(Включенный)**, **Активный(Включенный)** и что-то типо того, надеюсь вы поняли.

Надеюсь на ответы и ваши идеи, так как сам не уверен, что в моей "модели" все правильно.

P.S. За возможные ошибки извините: я старался их не делать, но русский -  не мой родной язык

Answer (score 0):

> должна происходить через функцию или должен поменяться класс?

Конечно, менять и получать состояния надо через методы, а хранить в полях.

> Телефон ведь изначально может быть в двух состояниях: Выключенный и
>   Включенный(а тут уже в свою очередь Заблокированный или Активный(а тут
>   Главный экран или Настройки, или Звонки и т.д.))

Не надо все это в кучу мешать. Каждой гаммой состояний должно заниматься отдельное поле.

```
bool on;
bool unlocked;
```

Насчет активного экрана - тут сложно выбрать тип без конкретной задачи. Ограничено ли экранов, все ли они захардкодены? Нужно ли хранить список запущенных приложений или только активный экран? В целом, если захардкодены, то можно просто enum, а если нет, то лучше наверно применить что-то похожее на настоящий Android: тип `QString`, в нем "com.settings.Main" если открыт главный экран, "com.settings.Wifi" - настройки Wi-Fi и т.д. Можно также рассмотреть `QUrl`: screen://settings, screen://settings/wifi.